# Sending parameter when JS method called in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a table that looks something like this
[image]

Here's my code I haven't tried a lot.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="" data-scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Name</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" data-scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Phone</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" data-scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="">Email</div>
                </th>
                <th class="" data-scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title=""></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                <tr key={contact.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td data-label="Name" data-scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={contact.Name}>{contact.Name}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Phone" data-scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={contact.Phone}>{contact.Phone}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Email" data-scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={contact.Email}>{contact.Email}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-label="Action" data-scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Action">
                            <lightning-button variant="base" data-key={contact.Id} label="Edit" title="Base action" onclick={handleEdit} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                            <lightning-button variant="base" data-key={contact.Id} label="Delete" title="Base action" onclick={handleDelete} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactManager_CTRL.getContacts';

export default class ContactTable extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track editLabel;
    @track deleteLabel;
    @wire(getContacts, {accountId: '$recordId'}) contacts;

    handleEdit() {
        console.log('======== :: called');
    }

    handleDelete() {
        console.log('======== :: called' + this.deleteLabel);
    }
}
```

on click of the edit button I want to send a contact id or contact as a parameter, is there a way to achieve this?

How can I achieve this in LWC?

Comment: What you have tried so far? where did you get stuck? Can you edit the question and add minimal required code?

Comment: @sanketkumar I have added my code but there isn't a lot that I have tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the standard dataset property to access the data-* property of your element.

Just add the event as a parameter of your `handleEdit` function, get the clicked element using `currentTarget` and finally retrieve your `data-key` attribute from the `dataset`:

```
handleEdit(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.key);
}
```

You can learn more on how to use data attributes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Hi Fabien, could you perhaps add a bit more explanation here?

Comment: That's true I've been a little bit lazy here, I added a few more details :)